# Trying to save multiple field in Plugin

Tags: plugin, xml, fields

I can add a multiple select field to my plugin's xml file, like this for countries but when I save it, it only saves the value "array" in the parameters. I would like to save it as a comma separated list, OR an array. I just want it to save values, and restore the chosen selections on editing.

```
 <field
                name="country"
                type="sql"
                id="country"
                description="MYMUSE_FIELD_COUNTRY_DESC"
                filter="string"
                default="CAN"
                multiple="true" 
                size="8"
                label="MYMUSE_FIELD_COUNTRY_LABEL"
                message="MYMUSE_FIELD_COUNTRY_MESSAGE"
                query="SELECT country_3_code as value, country_name as country FROM #__mymuse_country 
                ORDER by country"
            />
```

Comment: I think that `filter="string"` is used for '<input />' elements not list boxes. Also try to replace `country_3_code` with an integer-type column like `id` and use `filter="int_array"`. Set `default="Z"` where Z is the id that matches Canada in your table.

Comment: Answered! The filter="string" was the problem. Without that it works as expected. It gets saved, for example, as "country":["AIA","ATG","CAN"],

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the comments on this question, the answer is to remove `filter="string"` attribute from XML manifest file.

Answer (score 4):

Use `value` and `title` (not country) in the sql.  I believe your SQL should be as follows:

`SELECT country_3_code as value, country_name as title FROM #__mymuse_country ORDER by country`

See [SQL form field type](http://docs.joomla.org/SQL_form_field_type) for other variations that might be more suitable for your need.

Comment: Thanks for looking. I specify the id="Country". I use this field in a component form and all is well. It seems the plugin cannot save an array in params. Looking for a way to intervene in the save plugin process.
I get this in the post:

Comment: I get this in the post:
    [jform] => Array
        (
            [enabled] => 1
            [access] => 1
            [ordering] => 0
            [folder] => mymuse
            [element] => shipping_standard
            [params] => Array
                (....

                    [country] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => ALB
                            [1] => BLR
                        )
                )
        )

    [task] => plugin.apply
    [093bc641cdc06549ef53b4b57bfed980] => 1

Comment: The id is fine, it's the SQL that needs adjustment...you have to use "title", not "country" there.